# Using buffer formed from sprintf as a input to sscanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[50];
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    sprintf(buffer, "%%%dd %%%dd %%%ds", a ,b ,5);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Currently it is printing:
**%10d %20d %5s**

I need it to print as: **%d %d %5d**

as this buffer is used as a format in sscanf. not sure about the integer length which will be passed in string input in sscanf.

Not sure what to pass instead of **a** and **b**

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

> I need it to print as: %d %d %5d

```
sprintf( buffer, "%%d %%d %%%dd", 5 );
```

If you want to print a literal `'%'`, you need to give `"%%"` ("escaped percent") in the format string. The rest works as normal:

- "%%d" is

  - "%", followed by
  - "d"

And:

- "%%%dd" is

  - "%", followed by
  - a decimal from the argument list, followed by
  - "d"